# recover a slot parameter

Tags: c++, qt

I have a slot that receives a `QString`, and I want to assign the value for this parameter in another variable, or use it directly in another method of the same class.

The signal is emitted from some other class.

#### MyWidget.h

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H
#include"myclass.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets>
namespace Ui {
class MyWidget;
}

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget();
private:
    Ui::MyWidget *ui;
signals:
   void redirectData(QString data);
public slots:
   void sendData();
private:
   MyClass *myClass; // the object to receive and output the data
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

#### MyWidget.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include "ui_mywidget.h"
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myClass = new MyClass();
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(sendData()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(redirectData(QString)), myClass, SLOT(outputData(QString)));
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MyWidget::sendData()
{

    emit redirectData(ui->lineEdit->text());
    myClass->show();

}
```

#### MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class MyClass;
}

class MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();
    QString x;
private:
    Ui::MyClass *ui;
signals:
    void send2(QString);
public slots:
    void outputData(QString data);
};
#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

#### MyClass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include "ui_myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyClass)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText(x); // show x in plainTextEdit
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MyClass::outputData(QString data){

   x=data; // affect data a x 
}
```

[image: screenshot 1]

I want to display the value of `x` in the `QPlainTextEdit`.

This method is correct but does not fit with the rest of my code. I would like to preserve the value in `x`.

> MyClass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include "ui_myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyClass)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MyClass::outputData(QString data){
    ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText(data); 
}
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't works?

Comment: I tried with thoses methods and no result

Comment: Wait, are you implementing the _slot_ inside your constrctr .. not possible

Comment: Your code makes no sense. There is no signal, no connection, the second snippet has invalid syntax... Please read [ask] and provide [mcve] if possible.

Comment: what's `classe`? Do you use a custom compiler or typedefs?

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` macro is missing

Comment: yes the slot is declare in the constructor

Comment: `QString text = data` is valid

Comment: You can _use_ the slot inside contr .. but implementing it _inside_!!!

Comment: The slot is belongs to another class , the slot and the signal its correct , only I need to retrieve the parameter slot for use in another function

Comment: Please read the comments carefully again. We can't go in a circle. You have design and syntax errors.

Comment: I reformulate the data helped me if possible and thank you

Answer (score 0):

This now an OK question, if a tad wordy and basic. It is clearly mostly complete (the `.ui` files are missing - but don't include them!) and reproducible.
Thus, there are two things that you can do:

1. Simply set the value of the plain text edit in the slot:

   ```
   void MyClass::outputData(QString data){
     x = data;
     ui->plainTextEdit->insertPlainText(x);
   }
   ```

   You don't need to store the value in `x` at all, if you don't need it anywhere else in `MyClass`.
2. If `MyClass` should expose the `x` property to interact with other classes, you should make it so - and then use the notification signal to modify the widget:

   ```
   class MyClass : public QWidget {
       Q_OBJECT
       Q_PROPERTY(QString x READ x WRITE setX NOTIFY xChanged)
       QString m_x;
       Ui::MyClass *ui;
   public:
       explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = {}) {
         ui->setupUi(this);
         connect(this, &MyClass::xChanged, ui->plainTextEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::insertPlainText);
       ~MyClass {}
       Q_SIGNAL void xChanged(const QString &);
       Q_SLOT void setX(const QString &x) {
         if (m_x != x) {
           m_x = x;
           emit xChanged(m_x);
         }
       }
       QString x() const { return m_x; }
   };
   ```

#### Other notes

1. The `MyClass::x` member should not be public.
2. The containers passed as method arguments should be almost always of a const reference type - to avoid the premature pessimization of making copies of objects passed. Thus you should modify the signatures as follows - in both declarations (header files) and definitions (implementation - .cpp files):

   ```
   void MyClass::send2(const QString&);
   void MyClass::outputData(const QString &data)
   void MyWidget::redirectData(const QString &data)
   ```

   The old-style `connect` syntax you use demands normalized signatures and doesn't change - the `const` and reference must be dropped.
3. There's no need to store the `ui` by pointer - simply store it by value. The C++ language then automatically takes care of memory management for you, and the default compiler-generated destructor does the job.
4. In self-contained examples, there's no need to use the `.ui` files. Creating the widgets manually and laying them out is quite trivial, as you can see below.

#### A reworked example

Taking all this into account, this would be a self-contained demo - with no Ui files needed. Your question should have had something like this included - it's self contained, single file. The use of the properties is not undesirable to indicate intent: those are the changeable properties of the classes.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Source : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
   QHBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QLineEdit m_edit;
   QPushButton m_send{tr("Send")};
   QString m_text;
public:
   Source(QWidget *parent = {}) : QWidget(parent) {
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_edit);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_send);
      connect(&m_send, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{
         setText(m_edit.text());
      });
   }
   Q_SLOT void setText(const QString &text) {
      if (text == m_text) return;
      m_text = text;
      emit textChanged(m_text);
   }
   QString text() const { return m_text; }
   Q_SIGNAL void textChanged(const QString &);
};

class Destination : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
   QHBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QPlainTextEdit m_edit;
   QString m_text;
public:
   Destination(QWidget *parent = {}) : QWidget(parent) {
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_edit);
      connect(this, &Destination::textChanged, &m_edit, &QPlainTextEdit::setPlainText);
   }
   Q_SLOT void setText(const QString &text) {
      if (text == m_text) return;
      m_text = text;
      emit textChanged(m_text);
   }
   QString text() const { return m_text; }
   Q_SIGNAL void textChanged(const QString &);
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Source src;
   Destination dst;
   QObject::connect(&src, &Source::textChanged, &dst, [&](const QString &text){
      if (!dst.isVisible()) {
         dst.move(src.frameGeometry().topRight()); // align the windows
         dst.show();
      }
      dst.setText(text);
   });
   src.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```